# The ftp-simple extension in vs code is not showing remote file content

Tags: html, css, ide, visual-studio-code

I am not using git because I am under the constraints of a hosted CMS and can not SSH into their server.

I am trying to get ftp-simple to work in vs code so that I can edit a remote file save it and I can see the changes in the browser. Currently It can see the files on the remote server but wen I click on the files I can't see the content.

In my config file I have only input the authorization for the sftp and nothing more do I have to do something else in order to actually see the content?

This is what it looks like when I try to open the file. As you can see the file tree to the left is fully visible though.
[image]

Maybe someone else has had this problem before...

Comment: Its not a problem, sometimes due to internet connection, it takes some time to open content inside file, i also many times faced this :)

Answer (score 2):

For my situation I needed to specify port 22 in the config file:

`"port": "22",`